# How to traverse a graph in parallel with 2 or n processes

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am searching on the internet in order to find some algorithm that can traverse a graph in parallel using 2 or n processes without one process stepping into a previously visited node of the other so I can speed up the total scanning task of the whole graph, but I can't find anything. Is there any algorithm that can help me do such task in parallel? is it worth it?

Note : 
n processes share the same memory of visited and tovisit nodes

thank you

Comment: You should also indicate what is your memory model. Is it shared memory?

Comment: I think this case looks like a producer consumer problem, but if I make processes wait for each other then it is worth it?

Comment: I would try doing it as a producer consumer indeed but writing and reading from the queue in blocks rather then a single element, and doing some extra work when adding to make sure the elements is not visited since it was last checked

Comment: yes, they can have loops with each other more the one time

Comment: the question has already been answered(accepted) but I was just curious to know about that are you modifying the actual data graph wile traversing. Is your traversal read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the consumer-producer model for traversing the graph - but with some modifications from the pure model:

- Read and write to the queue in blocks, rather then element at a time, also update the `visited` set in blocks. It will save you the synchronization time - which will be needed to be done less frequently.
- When you do modify the queue (and `visited` set) - you should do some extra work to make sure you don't add data that was already visited since the set was last checked.

Note that with this approach - you are more then likely to search some vertices a few times - but you can bound it with the frequency the queue and `visited` set are updated.

Will it worth it? It is hard to say in these things - it is dependent on a lot of things (graph structure, size, queue implementation, ...).

You should run a few tests and try to fine tune the parameter for "how often to update", and check which is better empirically. You should use [statistical tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) ([wilcoxon test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) is the de-facto standard for this usually) and determine if one is better then the other.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the bulk of the time is spent on actual traversal, you could traverse the graph on a single thread, and queue up the work at each node to be processed in parallel from multiple processes. Once you have work in a queue, you can use a simple producer-consumer model.

Comment: so you say that I need to split the work of collecting the nodes of each process by n process, and gathering the new nodes to be visited by a single process?

Comment: A model like this would keep the graph traversal simple (use whatever algorithm you are using today), and make it easy to parallelize the work being performed at each node.